# Migrating from VSS to TFS. What is the benefit of creating separate projects?

Tags: team-foundation-server

We have a Visual SourceSafe installation that 4 developers collaborate on.  Inside that there are 30 or so independent projects in different top level folders.

Is it necessary for us to create a new TFS "Project" for each of those 30 items, or can we simply place them in the same overarching project folder... possibly assigning permissions to each?

The reason I ask is because I'm demo-ing the migration now and it takes a long time to migrate and create the "New Team Project" within Visual Studio in order to create a 1:1 correlation.

What are the other benefits I may get from using separate projects in TFS?

Answer (score 2):

Separate Team Projects in TFS will provide separate scope for permissions and policies on the source tree (e.g., check-in comment requirements), a separate project portal site and reports (if you're using them), separate scope for work items (again, if you're using them), and separate scope for automated build definitions.

You might check out this article "Visual Studio TFS Team Project and Collection Guidance" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983486.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if I can set granular permissions within a single project?

Comment: Yes.  You can set granular permissions on folders and branches within your source tree.  Right click on a folder or branch and select "Properties...".  You will see a Security tab on the window that appears.